# Invalid character in header content [\"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\"]

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cors

I have a node.js server that is deployed in an ec2 instance of AWS. When I'm trying to access the service from my local machine using public ip of that machine it works fine but facing the following issue when port-forwarding to localhost through a vpn (openvpn - udp) to that ec2 instance.

```json
{"message":"Invalid character in header content [\"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\"]","error":{"code":"ERR_INVALID_CHAR"}}
```

I've checked the response header. It looks like the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 119
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2023 11:36:18 GMT
ETag: W/"77-cTRgoYzDiwRyCA8tFrP3F9sMLIg"
Server: nginx/1.22.1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:3001
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0
```

In my node.js serve I'm using the following code to set the response header.

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
});
```

Comment: There's a chance there's a hiddden character on that line. Consider writing the same line again or inspect the file with `hexdump`

Comment: @Evert I've checked the header but couldn't find anything unusual. I've updated the question including the response header. It works fine if  I'm not using the vpn.